# Cannot load underlying module for 'YMTreeMap'

Tags: ios, swift

I am Installing a pod "YMTreeMap" in my existing project while import the file it shows the error with "**Cannot load underlying module for 'YMTreeMap'** can anyone please help me with issues.

Configuration - Xcode 14.3

I tried 2-3 times removing the pod reinstalled it but no use.
I want to use that pod for tree chart[Like the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cuv4d.png) How to solve this problem or is there any other solution like different libraries.